# UML tools to visualize a code base?

Tags: php, uml

can one map all the application's objects to a UML map (maybe parsing through the code base) so one can have the objects visualized and see all the relations and the design patterns used?

Comment: What language? There is no tool that will do all of them.

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100372/good-tool-to-generate-dependency-diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/). It should be able to do everything you need.